# Eclipse printing symbols instead of 'chars' on console for C

Tags: c, eclipse, console

new to C. Trying to get it to work with Eclipse since it seems a lot easier to use then vi (formatting, syntax warnings before compiling etc).

Now my program works fine in a terminal but in Eclipse console it does not seem to work well.

I have found the source of error but I need some assistance fixing it.
For some reason Eclipse console does not like to re-locate the cursor to print over existing text (or so it seems). Because when I print regularly using printf(...) it prints fine.

I am using these functions to re-print and Eclipse console does not like it. I first re-locate the cursor with set_cur_pos(..)  and then in a for loop reprint my characters on top of existing text by calling put(..)

```
//
// Name:    put
// Description: calls putchar to place a character, then flushes stdout
// @param character - character to print onto console
void put(char character) {
    putchar(character);
    fflush( stdout);
} // clear

//
// Name:    set_cur_pos
// Description - sets cursor at a specific location on console
// @param rCursor - row location to place cursor
// @param cCursor - col location to place cursor
//
void set_cur_pos(int rCursor, int cCursor) {
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", rCursor, cCursor);
} // set_cur_pos
```

EG: I'd use it like this

```
/**

 * Description: Function prints a grid using cursor control.
 */
static void printOver(char grid[40][40]) {

    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {

        for ( j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
            set_cur_pos(i, j);
            put(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why Eclipse prints this out?

```
[2J[0;0H [0;1H*[0;2H [0;3H [0;4H [0;5HY[0;6H*[0;7H [0;8H [0;9H [1;0H [1;1H [1;2H [1;3H [1;4H [1;5HY[1;6H [1;7H [1;8H [1;9H*[2;0H [2;1H [2;2H*[2;3H [2;4H*[2;5HY[2;6H [2;7HY[2;8H [2;9H [3;0H [3;1H [3;2H [3;3H [3;4HY[3;5HY[3;6H [3;7H [3;8H [3;9H [4;0H*[4;1H [4;2H [4;3H [4;4HY[4;5H [4;6H [4;7H [4;8H [4;9H [5;0H*[5;1HY[5;2H [5;3H [5;4H [5;5H [5;6H [5;7H [5;8H*[5;9H [6;0HY[6;1HY[6;2H [6;3H [6;4H [6;5HY[6;6HY[6;7H*[6;8H [6;9H [7;0H [7;1HY[7;2H [7;3HY[7;4H [7;5H [7;6HY[7;7H [7;8H [7;9H*[8;0HY[8;1HY[8;2H [8;3H [8;4H [8;5H [8;6H [8;7H*[8;8H [8;9H [9;0H [9;1H [9;2H [9;3HY[9;4H [9;5H*[9;6H [9;7H [9;8H [9;9H [10;0H
[0;0H [0;1H_[0;2H [0;3H [0;4H [0;5HY[0;6H_[0;7H [0;8H [0;9H [1;0H [1;1H [1;2H [1;3H [1;4H [1;5HY[1;6H [1;7H [1;8H [1;9H*[2;0H [2;1H [2;2H*[2;3H [2;4H*[2;5HY[2;6H [2;7H*[2;8H [2;9H [3;0H [3;1H [3;2H [3;3H [3;4HY[3;5H*[3;6H [3;7H [3;8H [3;9H [4;0H*[4;1H [4;2H [4;3H [4;4HY[4;5H [4;6H [4;7H [4;8H [4;9H [5;0H*[5;1HY[5;2H [5;3H [5;4H [5;5H [5;6H [5;7H [5;8H*[5;9H [6;0HY[6;1H*[6;2H [6;3H [6;4H [6;5HY[6;6H*[6;7H_[6;8H [6;9H [7;0H [7;1HY[7;2H [7;3HY[7;4H [7;5H [7;6HY[7;7H [7;8H [7;9H_[8;0HY[8;1HY[8;2H [8;3H [8;4H [8;5H [8;6H [8;7H_[8;8H [8;9H [9;0H [9;1H [9;2H [9;3HY[9;4H [9;5H*[9;6H [9;7H [9;8H [9;9H [10;0H
```

Comment: I guess because Eclipse doesn't support VT100 escape sequence and choosed to ignore ESC.

Comment: It's as @MikeCAT guesses; Eclipse is not a terminal emulator and it's just not suitable for testing an environment that requires one.

Comment: Note: As your comments seem to use some documentation standard, you better have a look at Doxygen. That avoids redundancy (e.g. shaving the name of the documented function in the comment) and generates pretty neat output.

Comment: Doxygen doesn't work for single-line comments. It needs to use the default javadoc style comment, which is `/** ...... */`

Comment: Also, try using `Geany`, you might end up liking it and it has the real terminal at the bottom (where Eclipse has the 'Output' window)

Answer (score 0):

These \033[... escape sequences are not terminal portable, eg. between bash and cmd.
So I think the eclipse IDE console does not interpret them as a cursor set command.
The single one portable cursor command without using PALs is '\r', wich will set
the cursor to the beginning of the line.